# excel vba toggle hide/unhide range rows across multiple sheets, if cell value 0

Tags: vba, excel

i would like the below work across sheets "Summary", "W1", "W2", "W3","W4","W5"
but I am facing some issues, can you please help.

The code is to hide empty rows across the above sheets, to hide unused rows.
The above ranges are identical across all of the above sheets.
The button is to toggle hide/unhide rows.

Thank you!

link to my file: [my workbook](http://www.mediafire.com/file/9wwdh23qony3hgy/example.xlsm)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If CommandButton1.Caption = "Less Rows" Then
CommandButton1.Caption = "More Rows"
Else
CommandButton1.Caption = "Less Rows"
End If
On Error Resume Next
  With Range("a8:a91,a96:a121").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow
    .Hidden = Not .Hidden
  End With
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to loop between all the sheets? Does the code above give you an error? Does it do something you don't expect?  What issues are you facing?

Comment: It works great but only on the Summary sheet. I would like to use one button to perform same action across all the sheets I've mentioned. But on all other sheets i have a formula, and Xlblanks does not work. That's why I need sheets in the code and cell value (i think). But I don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: What defines an unused row? If there's NO data at all, in any cell in the row? Or is it mainly like, if Column B is empty, that's an "unused row"  for your purposes?

Comment: Sheet "summary" a blank row is a row with no data. On Sheets W1-W5 it will be a formula returning "".

Comment: Try checking values of the cell. `xlBlanks` check the content of the cell which can be a formula (it's not blank).

Comment: That's what causes the problem. I need the code work with both blanks and formulas returning "". Also, for the time being the code works on active Summary sheet, and I need it to work across Summary, then W1-W5 sheets, with one click only.

Comment: How many columns do you have? If it's not a lot, you can loop through each cell in the range to check the length, and if it's 0, then it's "empty" for you.

Comment: I only have 121 rows. I need a code that works on A8:A91 and A96:A121. If cell value is 0 or blank then hides the entire row meeting the criteria. Summary sheet is to hold the button. By clicking the button I want to hide all rows meeting the criteria, across all the mentioned sheets. The rows will be identical across all the sheets: Summary, W1,W2,W3,W4,W5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loops over all the rows in the range and checks for the values and also loop over all the sheets in the workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim iRow as Range
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim hidden_status As Boolean

If CommandButton1.Caption = "Less Rows" Then
   CommandButton1.Caption = "More Rows"
Else
   CommandButton1.Caption = "Less Rows"
End If

On Error Resume Next

For Each wsh in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   Set rng = wsh.Range("A8:A91,A96:A121") 
    For Each iRow in rng.Rows
        If iRow.Value = "" Then
           With iRow.EntireRow
                 hidden_status = .Hidden
                .Hidden = Not hidden_status
           End With
        End If
    Next iRow
Next wsh

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Masoud , it does loop now, but continuously and does not stop hahah. Brilliant try though. I am guessing it is because of Summary tab containing actual blanks and all other sheets containing formulas.

Comment: @AnnaZet Get rid of `On Error` lines to see the actual error. Try step by step running (hit `F8` on your keyboard for that purpose). Check the part that I am gonna add in a minute (The part that I left to you). It cannot run forever. It will go to next row no matter what. You need to be patient though. It is running over 726 rows and by a for-loop not a filtering technique. Which takes some time.

Comment: Let me find a way to upload the workbook. Maybe it will make it easier. I don't want to take anyone's time (too much, hahah) I have spent so many hours on this code, and the one i am using now, is the best so far.

Comment: Link added to my first post. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AnnaZet no need to upload your file. If you consider my comment for running step-by-step you would find out what's going on. The range would not change for each worksheet and it stays in the first active worksheet which is "Summary" in your case because you have the button there. Check it out now.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I think I should be able to alter it a tiny bit to have effect on desired sheets only. I really appreciate you spent time to help me.